# Alternate of If condition in AWS state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

I do have a scenario in which input Json field has a map of 3 fields and on the existence of each I want to execute a lambda. I am trying this with choice state which works fine till not more than one condition is true. In my scenario ,I can have 2 conditions also true which in turn should invoke the next states of 2 choice condition.
It seems choice is an alternative of switch case and I am looking for an if condition with condition check.
Please share any example fir such case.

sample json : -

```
  "events" : {
         
         "event" : {
            "EVENT_1" : "ACTIVE",
            "EVENT_2" : "ACTIVE"
          }
    
     }
```

Sample State Machine :-

```
   ChoiceStateX": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
          {
            "Variable": "$.event.EVENT_1",
            "StringEquals": "ACTIVE",
            "Next" : "Event_1"
          },
          {
            "Variable": "$.event.EVENT_2",
            "StringEquals": "ACTIVE",
            "Next" : "Event_2"
          }
          
          }
          }
```

event in the events json is not a fixed field. It can just have one event_1 or 2 or it can even have 3 events. As many events are there it should call those many Tasks.
So the "Next" is totally dynamic and dependent on the input Json.
Please suggest how can i tackle this state.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example of the condition logic?  For example:  If all A,B,C fields are present, then do X;  if A,B then do Y, etc?  Or is it if  A,B,C then do X,Y,Z?

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. Can you please edit it to add more detail? I notice you have tagged your question with AWS Step Functions -- is this the service you are trying to use?

Comment: Hi @fedonev , I have update the question with Sample.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding:  Your input is a map of one or more events.  Each event has a type and status.  Each type has its own set of tasks.  If an event's status is `ACTIVE`, execute its type's tasks.

A way to solve this is to insert a [Map state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) in front of your Choice state.  The Map runs your Choice state once for each
element of the input array.  Each Choice state invocation's input is a single event from the array.

Map accepts an *array*, so you will need to convert your map-of-events input into an array-of-events.  If you cannot convert the input to an array before the state machine executes, a Lambda task placed in front of your Map can do the job.